# How to make TranslateAnimation update position while animating

Tags: java, android, android-animation

So while my `TranslateAnimation` goes through its 10 second animation, its position doesn't actually update at all.

The only time it DOES update is when the animation finishes.

So how can I get the `TranslateAnimation` to update its position WHILE it is animating?

By update its position, I mean, if I check for its position, IE; the top bottom left and right coordinates of the view, I should get a different set of numbers if it has moved.

But in this case, I am getting the position of the view's ORIGINAL location, which is not what I want. I want the position of the View AS it is moving during its animation, but there seems to be no way to do that.

Comment: What API are you targeting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using an [ObjectAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html)? The following code would actually move your view instead of just animating:

```
ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(yourView, "translationX", 0.0f, yourHorizontalTranslationTarget);
ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(yourView, "translationY", 0.0f, yourVerticalTranslationTarget);
```

Note that `yourHorizontalTranslationTarget` and `yourVerticalTranslationTarget` are absolute values in pixels, rather than a percentage.

You could then join them in an [AnimationSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html) so they would be executed at the same time.